# How to read serialized data (sent through Jquery POST) in MVC collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, collections

I have a form and one submit button click, i serialize my form and send it to MVC action.

**Jquery code**

```
           var formCollection = $('form').serialize();
           var path = $(this).attr('data-content-url');              

           // check if no more error 
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: path,
                   cache: false,
                   data: { collection: formCollection },
                   datatype: 'json',
                   success: function (data) {
                       // do stuff
                   }
               });
```

**MVC side**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MethodName( FormCollection collection )
    {
    }
```

i do get serialize data in my collection variable as

```
name=test&id=1 as collection[0]
```

How can i break this collection[0] so that this `name` and `id` can be assigned directly to class parameter, something like

```
Person p = new person { collection["name"], collection["id"] }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

this worked, create a new helper class which convert your serialized data in formcollection as you would normally expect

```
private FormCollection DeSerialize(FormCollection form)
{
  FormCollection collection = new FormCollection();
  //un-encode, and add spaces back in
  string querystring = Uri.UnescapeDataString(form[0]).Replace("+", " ");
  var split = querystring.Split(new [] {'&'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();      
  foreach (string s in split)
  {        
    string text = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("="));
    string value = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=")+1);

    if (items.Keys.Contains(text))
      items[text] = items[text] + "," + value;
    else
     items.Add(text, value);
   }
   foreach (var i in items)
 {
   collection.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
 }            
   return collection;
 }
```

Comment: Before anyone uses this method, just found an error where if your data contain ````&```` as a text in it, this code wont work

Answer (score 0):

you need to Deserialize using your model

try this

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(collection);

var name = response.name ;
var id  = response.id;
```

use foreach loop , to get more records from  list

Comment: I am not using Modal to display my data on my form initially. I just have 2 textboxes on my page and then serialize them to send the data to MVC controller. I replaced my code against you modal with my classname but it errors out ````Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0.```` data i am passing as collection is ````"name=test&id=1"````